# Relation between image integral and statistical value

Tags: opencv

I recently read about image integral and I can understand the mathematical way of doing it. Some how, I noted that it is as well can compute the statistical value such as mean, std dev, variance. So, the question is how to calculate the statistical value after the integral image is done? We can find the statistical value from a normal image therefore why and how do we need integral image and then find statistical value for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each pixel of the integral image (also called summed area table) contains the sum of all pixels that lie in the top-left area from this pixel. By using smart subtractions and additions you can actually get a sum of any rectangular area:
[image: Summed area table]
*[ Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table ]*

```
SUM(ABCD) = C - B - D + A
```

(from the `[0, 0], C` rectangle subtract two rectangles `[0,0], D` and `[0,0], B` and add back `[0,0], A` which was subtracted twice).

This is very handy because you can get the sum of any area just using 4 trivial operations. In other words, it's blazing fast and independent on the size of the area!

If you want to get an average of the area, just divide its sum by its size.

Getting variance is a bit trickier - you will need two integral images. One will be classical and the other one will be based on squared values - first square all intensities and then make the integral image from them. The rest is just plugging values in the following equation:

```
Var(area) = Avg(area^2) - Avg(area)^2
```

You get the first term from the squared integral image and the second term from the classical integral image. It's still only 9 simple operations to calculate. Neat, isn't it?

Comment: I think I understand what you meant here. According to opencv documentation on cvIntegral, how do you defined the "local window" or from the image the "rectangular box"?

Comment: Using its coordinates. You can access pixels of the integral image just like in the regular image. They just have a different meaning.

Comment: Em...Do you mean I need to defined the local window and then computes the statistical value again after computing cvIntegral? How is it considered fast? I'm confusing right now.

Comment: You define a local window using coordinates, don't you? You just need 4 (or 9) operations to find an average (or variance) of a local window. You need to precompute the integral image though.

Comment: Yup. Correct me if I'm wrong. So, 1st: computes cvIntegral, 2nd: defined local window (eg. 3x3) for the integral image output, 3rd: find the statistical value based on the integral image output?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Average/variance for each window can then be computed in constant time, independent of its size (be it 3x3, 5x5 or 64x64).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and efforts. +1.